Bitbucket pipelines conditional trigger mode
I need to dynamically set the trigger of a step to manual or automatic based on the value of an ENV VAR.
my actual code:
definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &setup
        name: Setup
        script:
          - echo "Setup!"
          - echo 'export CLEANUP="$CLEANUP"' >> env.sh
        artifacts:
          - env.sh
    - step: &cleanup
        name: Cleanup
        script:
          - |
            source ./env.sh
            if [ "$CLEANUP" == "true" ]; then
              echo "Cleaning up.."
            fi
  pipelines:
  custom:
    custom-one:
      - variables:
          - name: CLEANUP
            default: "true"
      - step: *setup
      - step: *cleanup

I want to have the cleanup step to be triggered automatically or manually if $CLEANUP value is true or false.
I tried to add trigger: manual using condition with no luck.
I don't know if it is possible to achieve..
